# When using xsl:analyze-string, i want to identify the value that matches

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have to go over a complete XML and identify if certain characters exists and which ones. I have the following, matching on text()

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[$~#^]">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="'yes'"/>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="'no'"/>
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

But what I want is to output the value that doesnt match.

this xml should output $ and ~.

```
<sample>
  <test>this is #^test1</test>
</sample>
```

Comment: Your subject says "i want to indentify the value that matches", your text "what I want is to output the value that doesnt match". And that example suggests you want something like `('$', '~', '#', '^')[not(contains('this is #^test1', .))]` (respectively in the template `('$', '~', '#', '^')[not(contains(current(), .))]`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, that looks like an answer to me.  If you put it in an answer, the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the result in the sample you could use e.g.

```
('$', '~', '#', '^')[not(contains('this is #^test1', .))]
```

(respectively in the template)

```
('$', '~', '#', '^')[not(contains(current(), .))]
```

Comment: This works well for all nodes, If I want to extend the check to include the attribute too, what can I do? Can you please guide me?

Comment: A `<xsl:template match="@* | text()">` matches all attribute nodes and all text nodes, you then only need to make sure you process attribute nodes with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>`. If you can't figure it out ask a new question with a sample of the XML and the result you want.

Comment: Thank you. I have asked a new question.